# Adding editable Excel (or Access) table in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel, personal-geodatabase, ms-access

I have flood data from the past ten years written in an Excel table. Now I would like to connect the table to ArcMap, so I can join it with the shapefiles. Normally this isn't that hard, but because we talk about floods, we want to hold the Excel table up to date.

What we want is a connection between ArcMap and Excel/Access so we can edit the tables and the data will automatically change in ArcMap (without a new import->join->etc..).

I think it is something with a geodatabase, but till now it isn't working at all.

Does somebody know if this is possible and how?

Comment: Bring it to access as linked table, load to arcgis

Answer (score 1):

1. open your excel and rename all you field names (with no character except "_" or letters, none of them should start with number)
2. Open ArcCatalog
3. Explorer you folder and create a New Personal Geodatabase (By right click to that folder / New / New Personal Geodatabase)
4. close ArcCatalog and open the geodatabase by Access
5. Import your excel data to this geodatabase
6. open ArcMap and explore your table (you can edit,append,delete,join your table using arcmap)

You can upload data using add theme but you cannot find if any of you data is missed. So is better to use this method because if any error of you excel data access will create a table with errors so you can find your data that cant be imported.

Comment: When I have joined it to an feature and I add a new flood in Access, will this new flood automatically join the table (and feature) in arcmap?

Comment: These are steps to have a clean table. Than you can create a new joined feature inside this geodatabase (Geometry+table). You can open this new feature and edits it even by access even by arcmap but remember do not make changes to other tables or do not make changes on field of indexes or geometry (geometry must be added by using arcmap not access)

Comment: So in the end I will have one big personal database right? With my Access(Excel)tables, with my features and maybe also with the colorstyle in it? Then everything is linked on eachother and some new added floods will show automatically

Comment: yes you will have a geodatabase with excel and geometry (not colorstyle, they cannot stored inside geodatabase). 
But if you have created a new feature with joined field, forged the excel, you table will be inside new feature. Than you should work with new feature created.

Comment: Alright, To make a test I added Year2017 to the table in Access now, but the exceltable doesn't change to a new one with the Year2017 field in it.

Comment: Dear, both tables function as two different tables even if they have join. You have to create a feature class with join of two tables than you should update this table no more the two old tables. These edits you can apply from arcmap and access. I have tested several time this and worked with this logic. All you have to do is open arcmap, upload table and geometry, create a join between geometry and table, after join export you feature class into a new one. This new feature class have to have both tables (Geometry table and excel table).

Comment: After creating this new feature class you have to work with this feature class (by arcmap) and with this table (by access). For example if you have stored this feature class with name "Test1_join" you should work with this name with both programs (arcmap and access). if you update old tables they are not gonna update the joined feature created.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I have an idea about it now and go to try some things by trial and error.

Comment: Okay one another thing.. When I add a new flood to the table, I always have to export it to a new feature or add the feature to the map again right? The edits do not change because of a "refresh" button or something?

Comment: if you have a mother table (two joined table), you can add new data by adding new field using access or edit old data, you can do all changes (but do not touch index field and geometry field, than you will have trouble). If you wanna change just geometry you should use arcmap (you can use arcmap even for changing table data). You can export and join only if you have to many changes that don't worth the time to edit one by one in access.

Comment: the logic is create a base feature class and edit it where you are more comfortable (or you colleges are more familiar). If you have big data than repeat the first step by join and export ;)